# ORG domain contact update take longer?

Tags: domain

I've managed several domains for years, no problem, but there is one ORG domain that is becoming a headache. Bought this domain at e-datarack who now appears as secureserver.net. The thing is due to a client request I performed a contact update information on this ORG domain, the confirmation email was sent and yes I confirmed.

- But the update is not taking place, it says it would take about 5 days.
- Those five days just passed and nothing.
- Whenever I try to initiate another update the process begins and takes place, but at the end it tells me it's invalid and can't go on.
- A message appears saying there are pending updates taking place that WILL BE SOON APPLIED.
- There is an option to "cancel" the update, but it doesn't work.

In the meantime I'm in the middle of a full server migration and right now I can't even update the DNS because of this unresponsive behavior on the domain panel (edatarack - secureserver.net).

Just tried performing THE SAME update on 5 different domains (just to test what happens), and all .com domains and one local ORG (actually ORG.GT) were updated in the matter of minutes. It's just the plain ORG that it's taking too long.

Is it possible that plain ORG domains take longer for contact updates? compared to plain .com and org.whatever?

The reason I'm asking this here is because nobody at edatarack or secureserver is replying, in fact there is no way to contact them except by phone and one ultra hidden contact form with automated responses. I got one reply saying they are so sorry that cannot do more, but there is a huge load of work due to covid, and person to person attention might take more waiting than expected.

I don't like this. edatarack used to be a company with humans, had a lot of issues and that's why I left (hosting) but left some domains on the registrar account (just the domains), as I didn't have any need for support I didn't notice they... over the years... removed interaction, contact forms, support tickets, etc. It's just an automated front end, so I'm left alone. The only thing I wonder is as asked above, if the plain ORG domains take longer for updates.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Anaksunaman, I'm in the waiting. Just spent a few hours on the phone with them and... there is no answer, they just couldn't give me an explanation and just told me to try A, B, C, same procedure over and over, now diff session, now diff browser, etc. How boring. They know and confirm this is not the usual case and tried to contact techs with higher powers with no luck, and as you point out, they mentioned COVID affecting waiting times and having lost workers, so I'll just have to wait. And BTW confirmed plain ORG shouldn't take any longer than any other domain.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that plain `.org` domains take longer for contact updates compared to plain `.com` and `org.whatever`?

Theoretically, yes.

Various [generic top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain)(gTLDs) such as `.com` and `.org.` and [country-code top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) (ccTLDs) such as [.org.gt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gt) are maintained by separate entities. In the case of "plain" `.org` domains, these are administrated by the [Public Interest Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Interest_Registry). This means that [Verisign](https://www.verisign.com/) (who administers `.com` domains, among others) and the Universidad del Valle de Guatemala (who apparently administers `.gt` domains) could potentially be "more responsive" in updating contact information than, say, the PIR.

Anecdotally, however, I have never noticed a significant delay in updating  `.org` domains (in fact, I have a "plain" `.org` domain that was updated just a few days ago). You may want to consider contacting the client to see if the registrar (edatarack/secureservers.net) sent them some sort of confirmation request as well. But with that said, you may simply be stuck waiting for those changes or need to pursue contacting the registrar yourself (again), despite any difficulties.

---

*As a side comment, I am not certain I would entirely overlook a work backlog due to the current virus outbreak. Being patient may be the only feasible option at this point, beyond perhaps transferring the domain to a different registrar (which might also take some time).*

---